# using python array in recursive function cause the reference loss

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, combinations

I tried to solve the question in a recursive way which is known as letter combinations of a telephone number.

In this question, telephone numbers are mapped to letters and for a given digits, the combinations of letters corresponding to the given digits are asked.

```
dic = {
    '2': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    '3': ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    '4': ['g', 'h', 'i'],
    '5': ['j', 'k', 'l'],
    '6': ['m', 'n', 'o'],
    '7': ['p', 'q', 'r', 's'],
    '8': ['t', 'u', 'v'],
    '9': ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
}

Input: "23"
Output: ["ad", "ae", "af", "bd", "be", "bf", "cd", "ce", "cf"].
```

I tried to solve it with recursion function but I got the unexpected output `[""]`.

```
def telephoneHelper(digits, index, ans):
    if(index==len(digits)):
        return ans
    else:
        tmp=[]
        for letter in dic[digits[index]]:
            for an in ans:
                tmp.append(an+letter)
        ans=tmp
        telephoneHelper(digits, index+1, ans)

def telephoneNumberRec(digits):
    ans=[""]
    if(len(digits)!=0):
        telephoneHelper(digits, 0, ans)
    return ans

ans=telephoneNumberRec("23")
print(ans)
```

I know there are many answers related to this topic but I am trying to understand the problem in this code.

Comment: in the `telephoneHelper` function, you need to add a return statement: `return telephoneHelper(digits, index+1, ans)`

Comment: Because your `telephoneNumberRec` **always returns `ans`** which is *always just `ans = [""]`. You've done nothing to change `ans`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add two return statements (one in the telephoneNumberRec and one in the telephoneHelper function) so that the recursion actually works. The working code would look like this:

```
dic = {
    '2': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    '3': ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    '4': ['g', 'h', 'i'],
    '5': ['j', 'k', 'l'],
    '6': ['m', 'n', 'o'],
    '7': ['p', 'q', 'r', 's'],
    '8': ['t', 'u', 'v'],
    '9': ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
}
def telephoneHelper(digits, index, ans):
    if(index==len(digits)):
        return ans
    else:
        tmp=[]
        for letter in dic[digits[index]]:
            for an in ans:
                tmp.append(an+letter)
        ans=tmp
        return telephoneHelper(digits, index+1, ans)

def telephoneNumberRec(digits):
    ans=[""]
    if(len(digits)!=0):
        return telephoneHelper(digits, 0, ans)
    return ans

ans=telephoneNumberRec("23")
print(ans)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
combinations = []
def telephoneHelper(digits,index, ans):
    n = len(digits[0])
    for i in range(n):
        item = ans + digits[0][i]
        if (index==len(digits)):
            combinations.append(item)
        else:
            telephoneHelper(digits[1:],index+1, item)
    return(combinations)


def telephoneNumberRec(input_):
     a = []
     for letter in input_:
          a.append(dic[letter])
     return (telephoneHelper(a, 0, '')) # a = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]

print (telephoneNumberRec('23'))
```

output:

```
['ad', 'ae', 'af', 'bd', 'be', 'bf', 'cd', 'ce', 'cf']
```